# Java extends class with inner class type

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, type-parameter

I have the following sample code and produce a "type parameter is not within its bound" error on the last line. Class C/D reuses lots of code from A/B thru the inheritance. How would I defined class Y to not have the error and still uses class D for type parameter? Is there a way I can define class D to use A.B but still has the signature of D extends S for class Y?

```
public abstract class S<E extends S<E>> extends somethingElse {}
public abstract class R<E extends S<E>> {}

public class A extends Z {
  public class B extends S<B> {
  }
}

public class C extends A {
  public class D extends A.B {
  }
}

public class X extends R<B> {}  // OK
public class Y extends R<D> {}  // Error: Type parameter D is not within its bound; should extends S<D>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to compile, you can change `E extends S<E>` to `E extends S<? super E>`:

```
public abstract class R<E extends S<? super E>> {}
```

The cause of this problem is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975038/7294647) that I answered earlier today.

Without the bounded wildcard, `D` was extending `S<B>` instead of `S<D>`.